# rails3 + unobtrusive javascript + mobile - has anyone gotten this to work?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, mobile, unobtrusive-javascript

I have a simple rails project which makes use of unobtrusive Javavscript for ajax link/form processing. Everything works great on the desktop.

Now, I'm trying to make the site mobile.  My understanding is that this involves the following steps:

1. Enabling the **ApplicationController** to change the `request.format` to `:mobile`.  Normally this is done with a filter which reads the incoming request properties and maybe sets `request.format = :mobile`:

   ```
   before_filter :adjust_format_for_mobile
   ```
2. Adding some lines to **mime_types.rb**:

   ```
   Mime::Type.register_alias "text/html", :mobile
   Mime::Type.register_alias "text/javascript", :mobilejs
   ```
3. Adding some new lines to the `respond_to` blocks for `format.mobile`, and `format.mobilejs`

   ```
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js 
     format.mobilejs
     format.html { redirect_to @post }
     format.json { render json: @post }
   end
   ```

I've tried to do all of these in various ways.  I tried doing #1 "by hand" inside the controller, then tried mobile-fu.  I tried various things in #2 like "`application/javascript`".  I also tried various ways of doing #3 (e.g. explicit render).

I can get the application to do everything except process an ajax call from a mobile browser.  It will either not find the appropriate template, or render the template as `text/html` rather than Javascript.

I've been through the Railscast for mobile detection (#199), as well as a number of questions/answers here (which seem a little outdated maybe).  I can't get this working.

So my question: has anyone been able to make this work?  If so can you offer a simple 1,2,3 for how to do it?  I think the problem is that the documentation is thin on the unobtrusive javascript + mobile issue, and various things that have worked in the past are no longer working in rails 3 (maybe)?  At this point I'm willing to do almost anything (e.g. major reconfiguring) to get this working.  I'm even willing to dump the unobtrusive javascript bit and do things in a "non-rails" way if I need to.

Thanks